# Why can't I find the Karin Kuruma?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Why can't I find the *Karin Kuruma* car in the southernsanandreasuperautos.com website? Do I have to do a specific heist/setup/mission or be at a certain level? I'm level 25 in GTA Online.

Answer (score 7):

You have to finish the Fleeca Job, which is the first heist you unlock. You don't have to be the heist leader to unlock it, you just have to finish the mission, either as heist leader or joining someone else's heist.

Comment: Also, there are 2 different Karin Kuruma vehicles that can be purchased. The regular civilian car for $95k and the armored one for roughly $600k. If you look at the page to buy the cars, sort by price high to low, you should see it right near the top.