# Why can't I see or buy the Karin Kuruma?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Why can't I see or buy the Karin Kuruma on southernsanandreasuperautos.com? I have the 100k one. I have already done the Fleeca Job but I can't find it or buy it again.

I am playing on the PS3.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [Why can't I find the Karin Kuruma?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/218800/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja The awnser there sais to do the Fleeca Job which he already did

Comment: Also, there are 2 different Karin Kuruma vehicles that can be purchased. The regular civilian car for $95k and the armored one for roughly $600k. If you look at the page to buy the cars, sort by price high to low, you should see it right near the top.